# How can I create custom layout like the picture attached here?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

As I wanna have bottom layout with a centered round button in it. For showing the button in center I wanna make background layout expanded/ bulged around the round button at the center. I tried multiple solution but nothing worked for me. Someone here help me to achieve this!
[image]
I need a custom layout created like this with xml code

Comment: You can use a drawable.
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/graphics/drawables

Comment: `I need a custom layout created like this with xml code` - so create it, if it won't fit your needs post it in here and ask for suggestions. read about [custom drawing programmatically](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/custom-views/custom-drawing) in Android, few approaches available for this purpose, e.g. [9patch](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try online website that create shapes there is lots of sites available, you can search custom shape creator.